# BulkAdmin Role Doesn't Work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, linked-server, openrowset

There is a query that our BI team use. They can not execute the query because of the error below.

> Ad hoc access to ole db provider 'MSDASQL' has been denied. You must
>   access this provider through a linked server.

I granted the users to *sysadmin* role and they could execute the query.

But, i don't want to give *sysadmin* role to them. I tried to give them *bulkadmin* role but it did not work.

How can i do it without *sysadmin* role? The query is below :

```
create table #temp 
(username varchar(100), 
    id varchar(100), 
    ipaddress varchar(100), 
    ipaddress2 varchar(100),  
    time_todate varchar(100), 
    username_new varchar(80),
    portnumber varchar(100))  

insert  into #temp (username , id, ipaddress, ipaddress2 , time_todate,portnumber )

 select * from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL', 'DSN=PROXY', 
 'SELECT username, id,ipaddress ,ipaddress2,time_todate,portnumber 
    FROM session nolock 
    where portnumber in (''4589ERC-13#228:154'')' ) 

 select * from #temp;
```

Comment: Does this help? [SQL Server Ad Hoc Access to OLE DB Provider Has Been Denied Error](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4582/sql-server-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-has-been-denied-error/)

Comment: Unfortunately. It was already applied all the steps on that article before. The setting was already disabled from SSMS and i also checked the registry setting. It is set to 0 value. I dunno what to do now. :/

Comment: Did you ensure `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries` was enabled via configuration setting in SQL Server - see [OPENDATASOURCE query execution error while using SQL public account](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2015/07/21/opendatasource-query-execution-error-while-using-sql-public-account/)

Comment: Why can't a sysadmin simply create a linked server for them to use, so they wouldn't have to use OPENROWSET?  What they are doing could be used to load arbitrary drivers into the SQL Server process, and is really should require a sysadmin.